# Censored below and above

Tags: censoring

I thought I understood the intuition behind censoring but I need to be perfectly clear about one thing which confuses me.

In my course book I only have the example of censoring from below:

$P(y=1) = P(X'B + u > c) \implies$ after normalizing so that $c = 0 \implies P(X'B + u > 0) = P(u > -X'B) = $ by symmetry $= P(X'B > u) = F(X'B)$

where $F(X'B)$ is the CDF.

When censoring from above, how exactly are these steps written out? Is the following correct?

$P(y=1) = P(X'B + u < c) \implies P(X'B + u < 0) = P(-u > X'B) = P(X'B > u) = F(X'B)$

But is this correct? Shouldnt it be that when censoring from above we get $P(y=1) = 1 - F(X'B)$?

Comment: Hi Johanna. This is a MathJax enabled site. Please use [that](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated) for better readability.

Comment: What you're deriving looks like a probit model rather than a typical tobit model. The latter doesn't have the symmetry you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the latter model, we should get F(-X'B), correct? Because in the first we had P(XB > u) = F(XB) and in the second we have P(-XB >u) = F(-XB).

Comment: yes, it seems a "-" got lost going from $P(-u>X'B)$ to $P(u<X'B)$